# In Wordpress, how do I display sum from a column of a MySQL table in a page?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Say my database table is called "mytable", and it has the following data :

```
Id            Name             Category          Points
-----------------------------------------------------------
1             ABC               Good              40
2             DEF               Good              20
3             GHI               Bad               10
4             JKL               Good              30
5             MNO               Bad               20
```

And in my Wordpress page, I want to display the following:

```
Total Points for Good = 90
Total Points for Bad  = 30
```

Please help

Update I tried using the code given by @user3405706

in my function.php to use as Shortcode

```
      function sum_good() {
global $wpdb; 
$result_good = $wpdb->get_results("Select sum(points) as good_points from mytable where category='Good'");

        $haha= "Total Points for Good =".$result_good['good_points'];
        return $haha;
        /// do same for other category
        }
    add_shortcode('sumgood', 'sum_good');
```

But the shortcode display only :

```
Total Points for Good =
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: What you tried so far? Any code?

Answer (score 0):

Use sum() aggregate function and grouping:

```
select category, sum(points) amount
from test
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a30547/3/0)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I want to implement in to a wordpress page, not just a MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

global $wpdb;
$result_good = $wpdb->get_results("Select sum(points) as good_points from mytable where category='Good'");

echo "Total Points for Good =".$result_good['good_points'];

/// do same for other category

Comment: For a good understanding of $wpdb and its functions, please have a look on wordpress codex. URL: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb,

Use print_r() to debug the result by your query to database.